# Is using PyQT's QProgressbar in combination with generators efficient?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyqt4, generator

I'm trying to use the QProgressBar to update itself to show the progress of lengthy operations. My code is:

```
#yield trials
import sys
from PyQt4.QtGui import QDialog, QProgressBar, QPushButton, \
                    QLabel, QApplication, QVBoxLayout

def someprocess():
    bignumber = 1000000
    for i in range((bignumber+1)): 
        if float(i)/bignumber in [float(count)/10 for count in range(11)]:
            yield i, float(i)/bignumber

if __name__ == "__main__":
    it= someprocess()
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    mydialog = QDialog()
    myprogress = QProgressBar()
    mylabel = QLabel("Uninitiated.")
    mylayout = QVBoxLayout()
    mylayout.addWidget(mylabel)
    mylayout.addWidget(myprogress)
    mydialog.setLayout(mylayout)
    mydialog.show()
    try:
        value, percentage = it.next()
        while value != None: 
            value, percentage = it.next()
            myprogress.setValue(percentage*100)
            mylabel.setText("Currently at : %s" % str(value))
    except StopIteration:
        print "Completed!"
    except Exception, e:
        print "Unknown exception: ", repr(e) 
        raise
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: Looks like your UI is freezing until the the loop finished, is this your choice？

Comment: No, I'd rather it process live and not freeze. Thanks for noticing that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PyQt (Or generally speaking, the UI development) usually requires put the long-time run function into backend thread, so this will not blocking your UI thread, make it able to response the UI update/User interactive. so in this case, you need to put "`someprocess`" into backend thread(possibly inherit from QThread), and using signal-slot to update the UI. 
I modify your code, adding some changes. move the long-time run function into backend thread, now, the UI will not be freezing.

```
import sys
from PyQt4.QtGui import QDialog, QProgressBar, QPushButton, \
                    QLabel, QApplication, QVBoxLayout
from PyQt4.QtCore import QThread, pyqtSignal


def someprocess():
    bignumber = 1000000
    for i in range((bignumber+1)):
        if float(i)/bignumber in [float(count)/10 for count in range(11)]:
            yield i, float(i)/bignumber


class WorkerThread(QThread):
    progress = pyqtSignal(int)

    def run(self):
        it = someprocess()
        try:
            value, percentage = it.next()
            while value != None:
                value, percentage = it.next()
                self.progress.emit(percentage*100)
        except StopIteration:
            print "Completed!"
        except Exception, e:
            print "Unknown exception: ", repr(e)
            raise e

if __name__ == "__main__":
    it= someprocess()
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    mydialog = QDialog()
    myprogress = QProgressBar()
    mylabel = QLabel("Uninitiated.")
    mylayout = QVBoxLayout()
    mylayout.addWidget(mylabel)
    mylayout.addWidget(myprogress)
    mydialog.setLayout(mylayout)
    mydialog.show()
    w = WorkerThread()
    w.start()
    w.progress.connect(myprogress.setValue)
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with using multithreading. Guess I need to read up on those concepts before attempting to do this.

Comment: I finally got around to implementing multithreading. Thanks a lot for your help!